# Blender console formatted printing: Is there a maximum length?

Tags: python, command-line

With the default cube mesh and Blender 2.77, if I run this code in console:

```
for f in bpy.data.meshes['Cube'].polygons:
    for v in f.vertices:
        print("%f %f %f" % bpy.data.meshes['Cube'].vertices[v].co[:])
        print("%f %f %f" % f.normal[:])
    print("\n")
```

I get the following output (truncated for brevity):

```
-1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
-1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
-1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
-1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
-1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
-1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
-1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
-1.000000 0.000000 0.000000


-1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
0.000000 1.000000 -0.000000
...
```

However, with this:

```
for f in bpy.data.meshes['Cube'].polygons:
    for v in f.vertices:
        print("%f %f %f %f %f %f\n" % bpy.data.meshes['Cube'].vertices[v].co[:], f.normal[:])
    print("\n")
```

or even this:

```
for f in bpy.data.meshes['Cube'].polygons:
    for v in f.vertices:
        print("%f %f %f %f %f %f" % bpy.data.meshes['Cube'].vertices[v].co[0], py.data.meshes['Cube'].vertices[v].co[1], py.data.meshes['Cube'].vertices[v].co[2], f.normal[0], f.normal[1], f.normal[2])
    print("\n")
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 3, in <module>
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Why can I print 3 floats easily but printing 6 floats doesn't work? Is Python's formatted printing different that C's (in this respect)? Or is it something Blender specific? Is there a maximum limit on how many 'arguments' the format string can take?

Comment: print( "%f, %f" % (1, 2) ) , more information here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286401/print-multiple-arguments-in-python

Comment: @lemon Putting all the floats in a list works for program 3, but it is tedious to type. Is there any way to make it work for program 2 (with two separate lists)?

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points and combine format function as you need

Comment: @lemon Uh, that was not my problem. Anyways, it is solved now. Thanks

Comment: You can also change the end character of print from its default "\n" (carriage return) with `print(str, end=",")` for example.  Something like `cube = bpy.data.meshes.get("Cube")` and for `v in cube.vertices:` would make the code a whole lot more readable... and also I vote to close this q as it is not really about blender python or the console, rather a syntax error.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is primarily about python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python the string formatting operation ('%') accepts a single argument and in your first (working) example that's exactly what you've got as it's a single element with 3 components. in your other (not working) examples you're trying to pass multiple values to '%', each containing 3 values. Your solution is to simply combine them into a single tuple by appending them with the '+' operator :

```
for f in bpy.data.meshes['Cube'].polygons:
    for v in f.vertices:
        print("%f %f %f %f %f %f\n" % (bpy.data.meshes['Cube'].vertices[v].co[:] + f.normal[:]))
    print("\n")
```

Comment: This doesn't work directly (same error), but putting a parenthesis around the entire second argument (list1 + list2) makes it work. I can't edit it because SE wants me to edit more that 6 characters